# I wanted to create a list, but something went wrong

Tags: python

1. In general, you need to create a list of four-digit numbers from the list `[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 'B']`. That is, the task is to generate from the proposed elements `(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 'B)` all possible variations of tuples of 4 elements. Various variations including `(1,1,1,1)` and `('B','B','B','B')`
2. for example `[(1,2,4,5), (6,'B',1,2)]`
3. The problem is that I generate a list using 4x for, check through if 4 elements have accumulated in the list, then transfer it to a tuple and add it to a new list, but after the last for is triggered, generation stops.

```
aa=[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 'B']
s=[]
bb=[]
for a in aa:
    s.append(a)
    for b in aa:
        s.append(b)
        for c in aa:
            s.append(c)
            for d in aa:
                s.append(d)
                if len(s) == 4:
                    n=tuple(s)
                    bb.append(n)
                    s=[]
print(bb)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 4, 5, 6), ('B', 2, 1, 2), (4, 5, 6, 'B'), (4, 1, 2, 4)]
```

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve. Should the initial list be converted to a list of four item tuples that cycle if the length of the initial list is not a multiple of four?

Comment: the task is to generate from the proposed elements (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, ' B) all possible variations of tuples of 4 elements

Answer (score 2):

In a more pythonic way, I would write this with a comprehension list ([W3Schools on this topic](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)):

```py
aa = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 'B']

bb = [(a, b, c, d)
      for a in aa
      for b in aa
      for c in aa
      for d in aa]

print(bb)
```

This will create `bb` as a list containing all possible tuples `(a,b,c,d)` from `aa`

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with `itertools.product`. You can check the documentation on [itertools.product here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```py
from itertools import product
aa = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 'B']
bb = list(product(aa, repeat=4))
```

If you are not able to use `itertools` module, your code has a bug.

```py
aa=[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 'B']
s=[]
bb=[]
for a in aa:
    s.append(a)
    for b in aa:
        s.append(b)
        for c in aa:
            s.append(c)
            for d in aa:
                s.append(d)
                if len(s) == 4:
                    n=tuple(s)
                    bb.append(n)
                    s=[]           # <<-- here is a problem
print(bb)
```

You empty the list completely, removing also `a`, `b` and `c`, from it.
If you'd put `print(s)` before the `if`, you'd see this sequence. The second column shows the source of elements.

```
[1,1,1,1]    [a,b,c,d]
[2]          [d]
[2,4]        [d,d]
[2,4,5]      [d,d,d]
[2,4,5,6]    [d,d,d,d]
['B']        [d]
['B',2]      [d,c]
['B',2,1]    [d,c,d]
['B',2,1,2]  [d,c,d,d]
[4]          [d]
...
```

this repeats for some time, but eventually there comes a time, when `len(s) > 4`, and this is when iteration "stops", as you say. The if condition is never True after that.

I'd propose to rewrite it, for example like this

```py
aa = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 'B']
bb = []
for a in aa:
  for b in aa:
    for c in aa:
      for d in aa:
        bb.append((a, b, c, d))
print(bb)
```

or I like the [solution proposed by @Rafalon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76063387/15582061)

If you really insist on using `s` and `s.append(...)`, you'd do

```py
for a in aa:
  s.append(a)
  for b in aa:
    s.append(b)
    for c in aa:
      s.append(c)
      for d in aa:
        s.append(d)
        bb.append(tuple(s))
        s.pop()
      s.pop()
    s.pop()
  s.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood of your question, you want to create all possible combinations of elements from a list. You can try the following code:

```
from itertools import combinations #Import the necessary module

your_list = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 'B'] #Create a list

#Create combinations of four elements at a time
list_combinations = combinations(your_list, 4)

#Print combinations
print(list(list_combinations))
```